# $\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(1+ab)}$ must be a perfect square if it is an integer

Tags: number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Alternative proof that $(a^2+b^2)/(ab+1)$ is a square when it's an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer)

I came across this problem, but couldn't solve it.

> Let $a,b>0$ be two integers such that $(1+ab)\mid (a^2+b^2)$. Show that the integer $\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(1+ab)}$ must be a perfect square.

It's a double star problem in Number theory (by Niven). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Let the double star come here too !! ;). I gave +1 and a star. Let me wait for another one..

Comment: Done. It's now a double star problem in math.SE ;-).

Comment: @JBC : Ha ha, Yes..

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141383/seemingly-invalid-step-in-the-proof-of-fraca2b2ab1-is-a-perfect-squar/

Comment: New and better solution without using vieta jumping method here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer/646382#646382

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was an IMO(International Mathematical Olympiad)problem, Terence Tao among few others solved it. There is a technique that solves similar problems, here is a link http://www.georgmohr.dk/tr/tr09taltvieta.pdf

Comment: Good reference. +1.

Comment: +1 Excellent reference. This reinforces what one teacher once told me about the IMO's: the team/student that wins is not always the best mathematician but the one who had the best team to get the best tricky-solving resources.

Comment: Not that it matters, but Terence Tao didn't figure it out. Another Fields medalist, Ngo Bao Chau did... he got a perfect score on the IMO that year.

Comment: New and better answer without using vieta jumping here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer/646382#646382