# $\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{ab+1}=k$. Find $k$

Tags: integers

$a$ and $b$ are positive integers such that
$$\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{ab+1}=k$$
where $k$ is positive integer. Find all values $k$

#### My work:

$a$ is the root of the equation
$$x^2-kbx+b^2+1-k=0$$
Let $c$ is another root of this equation. Then
$c=kb-a$ and $ac=b^2+1-k$

Comment: Where did the problem come from? Probably there is an infinite class of solutions and not just finitely many, e.g. Mathematica finds $(a,b,k)=(509,131872738,259082),(346,41422082,119717),\dots$

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162785/fraca2b21ab-must-be-a-perfect-square-if-it-is-an-integer. See the links in the comments there.

Comment: @lhf This is not a duplicate.  This problem is slightly different from that link, and all the links in that thread.  However, similar techniques should be able to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k$ be a positive integer such that there exist positive integers $a$ and $b$ for which $$\frac{a^2+b^2+1}{ab+1}=k\tag{1}$$  Suppose that $(a,b)=(p,q)$ is the smallest positive integer answer to $(1)$ such that $p\geq q$ (in the sense that $p+q$ is the least possible).  Therefore, $t=p$ is a solution to
$$t^2-(kq)t+(q^2+1-k)=0.\tag{2}$$
This is a quadratic equation so there is another root $t=r$.  Note that
$$r=kq-p$$
so $r$ is an integer.

Suppose that $r<0$.  Let $f_0(x)=1$ and $g_0(x)=1$.  We want to show that for any non-negative integer $j$, there are polynomials  $f_j(x),g_j(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ with non-negative integer coefficients such that
$$k\geq f_j(q)\geq 3j$$
and 
$$p\geq g_j(q)\geq 3j+1.$$
Furthermore, $f_j$ has degree $j+1$ and $g_j$ has degree $j+2$ for $j>0$.

The case $j=0$ is trivial.  We proceed further by induction.  Suppose that $f_j(x),g_j(x)$ are known and satisfy the requirements.  Then, we have from $(2)$ that $pr=q^2+1-k$ or 
$$k-q^2-1=p(-r)\geq p\geq g_j(q).$$
Therefore, $k\geq q^2+1+g_j(q)$ and we can define
$$f_{j+1}(x)=x^2+1+g_j(x).$$
From $r=kq-p$, we get $kq-p<0$ or $p>kq$.  That is, $p\geq kq+1$.  Because $k\geq f_{j+1}(q)$, we have
$$p\geq q\ f_{j+1}(q)+1.$$
Hence, we define $$g_{j+1}(x)=x\ f_{j+1}(x)+1=x^3+x+1+x\ g_j(x).$$  Note that this construction guarantees that $f_{j+1}$ and $g_{j+1}$ has non-negative integer coefficients,
$$\deg f_{j+1}=\max\{2,\deg g_j\},$$
and
$$\deg g_{j+1}=\deg f_j+1=\max\{2,\deg g_j\}+1.$$
It follows that
$$\deg f_j=j+1$$
and
$$\deg g_j=j+2$$
for every positive integer $j$.  It can be easily seen that $$f_j(q)\geq f_j(1)=\max\{1,3j\}$$ and $$g_j(q)\geq g_j(1)=3j+1$$ for all positive integers $q$ and for every non-negative integer $j$.

From the result above, if $r<0$, then $k$ and $p$ are arbitrarily large, which is a contradiction.  Therefore, we must have $r\geq 0$.  We want to show that $r>0$ is also impossible.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $r>0$.  Then, $(a,b)=(q,r)$ is also a solution to $(1)$.  By minimality of $(p,q)$, $p+q\leq q+r$, or $p\leq r$.  That means
$$kq=p+r\leq 2r.$$
Hence, $r\geq \frac{kq}{2}$, so 
$$q^2+1-k=pr\geq p\left(\frac{kq}{2}\right)=\frac{kpq}{2}.$$
Therefore,
$$q^2+1\geq \frac{k}{2}(pq+2)\geq \frac{k}{2}(q^2+2),$$
since $p\geq q$.  That is,
$$k\leq 2\left(\frac{q^2+1}{q^2+2}\right)< 2.$$
Therefore, $k=1$.  However, by $(1)$, AM-GM implies
$$1=\frac{p^2+q^2+1}{pq+1}\geq \frac{2pq+1}{pq+1}>\frac{pq+1}{pq+1}=1,$$
which is absurd.  Therefore, $r>0$ cannot happen.

This means $r=0$, making $k=q^2+1$.  In this case, there always exists a solution with the minimal solution $(a,b)$ such that $a\geq b$ being
$$(a,b)=(q^3+q,q).$$
All integer solutions $(a,b)$ such that $a\geq b >0$ satisfies
$$(a,b)=\left(x_{s+1}^q,x_s^{q}\right)$$
for some positive integer $s$, where the sequence $\left(x_s^q\right)$ is defined by
$$x_1^q=q,$$
$$x_2^q=q^3+q,$$
$$x_s^q=(q^2+1)x_{s-1}^q-x_{s-2}^q$$ 
for $s=3,4,5,\ldots$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that, mod $ab+1$, $0=b^2(a^2+b^2+1)=b^4+b^2+1$. Therefore, $b^4+b^2+1 > 0$ is divisible by $ab+1$, thus $b(b^3+b) \geq ab$. So if $b \neq 0$, then this can be written as $k \leq b^2+1$ which entails (if $a > 0$), $c \geq 0$.

Take now, for a given $k$, $(a,b)$ a solution in non-negative integers with $a \geq b$ and $a+b$ minimal. Assume $b \neq 0$ (hence $ab>0$).

Then by minimality $c \geq a$ (since $(c,b)$ is a solution) thus $a^2 \leq ac = b^2+1-k \leq b^2$, so $a=b$. But this implies $a=b=0$, a contradiction. So $b=0$ and $k=a^2+1$.

The possible values of $k$ are thus exactly all the $x^2+1$ for integers $x$.