# $x^2+y^2=z^2(1+xy)$ prove $z=\min \{x;y;z\}$ (with $x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z^+}$)

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, diophantine-equations, contest-math

$x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $x^2+y^2=z^2(1+xy)$. Prove $z=\min \{x;y;z\}$

---

$$x^2+y^2=z^2(1+xy) \iff xy = \frac{x^2+y^2} {z^2} - 1$$. Assum $z>y \implies xy < x^2/z^2$, we have $xy \in Z \implies x> z$ then...stuck

Comment: Isn't the definition of $z$ circular?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem. I thought $z$ was supposed to be unknown!

Comment: possible duplicate of [$\frac{(a^2+b^2)}{(1+ab)}$ must be a perfect square if it is an integer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/162785/fraca2b21ab-must-be-a-perfect-square-if-it-is-an-integer)

Comment: Which in turn was closed as a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28438/alternative-proof-that-a2b2-ab1-is-a-square-when-its-an-integer

Comment: This is a different problem. We are not asked to show that $z$ is an integer. We are *given* that $z$ is an integer and shall prove $z\le x$, $z\le y$.

Comment: @Hagen, yes, but the way you solve the other problem(s) is to figure out what $x$ and $y$ have to be, and then it's immediate that $z^2$ is the square of the smaller of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Is there any way to find $a, b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1+ab \mid a^2 + b^2$

Comment: @Gerry, I would (and did, below) call this a variant, not a duplicate.  The $ab+1$ problem, restated in the terms of this question, essentially is to show that $(0,z)$ is the smallest integer solution. This question asks for the smallest positive integer solution, which is $(z,z^3)$.

Comment: @D3r0X4, the solution $(a,b) = (z,z^3)$ was written in the answer and comments. There are many others.

Comment: This should not be closed as a duplicate.  It contains the non-Diophantine problem of seeing that a proof by pure inequalities cannot work.  The Diophantine part is similar to, but somewhat more complicated than, and requires a bit more understanding of the structure, than the older questions on ab+1.

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of the $ab+1$ problem (an old and famous killer problem from the IMO), and is a corollary of its solution.  For fixed $z$, the solutions $(x,y)$ organize into a chain where the size of the solution can be reduced by moving down the chain until the minimal solution with $xy=0$ is reached. This smallest solution is $(0,z)$ or $(z,0)$. The smallest positive solution is adjacent to this one in the chain, and adjacent solution have one variable the same, so the smallest positive solution is $(z,t)$ or $(t,z)$ for some value of $t$ (larger than $z$, in fact $t = z^3$). This has $\min(x,y)=z$ and the other positive solutions have bigger values of $\min(x,y)$.  For the same reasons, in a positive solution, $\max(x,y) \geq z^3$.  The inequalities are a complicated way of saying that $(x,y)=(z,z^3)$ is the smallest positive integer solution to the equation.

There was a careful analysis of the $ab+1$ problem here:

[Seemingly invalid step in the proof of $\frac{a^2+b^2}{ab+1}$ is a perfect square?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141383/seemingly-invalid-step-in-the-proof-of-fraca2b2ab1-is-a-perfect-squar/)

Edit:

Actually the reduction process, applied to any *non* integer solution with fixed $z$, should eventually reach a pair $(x,y)$ with $0 < x < z \leq y$, so this problem can work only as a Diophantine question and is not derivable from inequalities.  The minimal solution overall will have $xy < 0$ and both variables less than $z$ in absolute size.