Is it possible to find an ellipse equation while given 3 arbitrary points on it? (no center or foci are given)
Hi I am dealing with an image processing issue where I have parts of an ellipse visible (which is a circle projection) while other parts of an ellipse are blocked by another objects on a scene. I wonder whether I can derive the center of such an ellipse.
Note that the ellipses are located in an arbitrary position and rotation angle

No, you need at least five points to find the ellipse. Or three points and some other information.

Thank you! In my case, it is fine I guess since I have plenty of pixels located on a theoretical ellipse. I wonder if it is ok to aproximate since actually none of the pixels sits exactly on an ellipse. What do you think

For fitting points to an ellipse see here, for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4738768/255730

The minimum number of points you need is 5 as far as I am aware
Let P,Q,R,S be four points the general conic passing through these four points is given by
$$(PQ)(RS)=\lambda(PR)(QS)$$ where PQ is the equation of the line joining P,Q and lambda is a parameter
Substituting the 5 the point will give you lambda but it has no guarantee of being an ellipse
Once you do have the equation finding the centre is trivial

Thank you very much sir. Can you please describe me the process in some pseudocode manner?

This is not extremely programmer friendly cuz you like have to hard code a really long formula for lambda but the calculation itself isn't extremely taxing its just disgusting to look at.

Lambda will come as a function of $x_i,y_i$ its best you multiply all the line equations by hand or wolfram and hard code the formula once u have lambda u can back substitute to get equation
